# USB audio interface not recognized on re-docking a Thinkpad

Tags: 12.10, sound, usb, thinkpad, docking

my Thinkpad X230 is sitting on a Lenovo docking station (Minidock Plus) and I have a USB audio interface (NI Komplete Audio 6) connected to the dock.
It works fine when I boot the computer while it is sitting on the docking station.

If I dock the Thinkpad (while running or while suspended) Ubuntu 12.10 does not re-connect the USB audio interface. Instead it continues to play back audio via the internal sound hardware.
The Komplete Audio 6 is shown in the sound settings but choosing it changes nothing (the sound is still being played back via the internal hardware).

I have to re-boot on the dock to get the USB audio running again.

Any ideas for correcting this behavior?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: Run `pactl list sinks | grep Name` -- is the USB device listed? If so, telling Pulseaudio to use it again should suffice. In any case, try restarting Pulseaudio (instead of rebooting), i.e. `service pulseaudio restart`. (I remember a time where my DAC would be found when trying to use MPD, but playing a Youtube video kickstarted it. Weird, I know, but maybe worth a try.)

Comment: Thanks and apologies for the delay in reply. While your suggestions are better than a reboot, I'd really prefer Pulseaudio to re-check automatically after each docking procedure.

Comment: You can probably hook a script rebooting PulseAudio (or resetting to the correct sink via `pactl`) to the ACPI event(s) which are fired on (un)docking. There are examples for such script hooks on the web (specifically for docking with ThinkPad, that is).

Comment: That said, I have observed the same behaviour. It is also solved by disabling the internal sound device in the "Sound" configuration thingy.